# Calculating new variable based on conditions from multiple rows

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am have trouble creating code to calculate nest initiation date from an original data frame that has multiple rows for each nest. My data set looks something like this:

```
NestID  JulianDate  Stage   HostEggs    HostYoung   NSTLAge NestFate
Nest01  146         IB         2           0         NA 
Nest01  149         NG         0           2         1  
Nest01  153         NG         0           2         5  
Nest01  156         NG         0           2         8  
Nest01  160         FL         0           0         NA       Fledged
Nest02  143         NG         1           1         5  
Nest02  147         D          0           0         NA       Depredated
```

What I would like to do is calculate initiation date for nest types that meet certain criteria. For Nest01 I want to use the midpoint between the last day with Stage IB and the first day with stage NG, and then subtract 12 days from that (the incubation period. So for this example the midpoint would be 147.5 and 12 days before that would be 135.5 for the initiation date.

For nests that were found during the nestling period, I want to calculate initiation date based on NSTLAge. For Nest02 I would need to subtract the nestling age from the Julian date and also subtract 12 days for the incubation period. So initiation date for Nest02 should work out to be 126 (143-5-12).

I am not particularly sure how to go about doing this. I have used dplyr to group by NestID but after that I am unsure about how to code for nests that fall under each classification. I have also tried setting up if statements, but from what I have found online that looks at each row separately and I need it to look at the entire group.

Any help people can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use dplyr, but I think this solves the problem.

```
NestID <- c(rep("Nest01",5),rep("Nest02",2))
JulianDate <- c(146,149,153,156,160,143,147)
Stage <- c("IB","NG","NG","NG","FL","NG","D")
HostEggs <- c(2,0,0,0,0,1,0)
HostYoung <- c(0,2,2,2,0,1,0)
NSTLAge <- c(NA,1,5,8,NA,5,NA)
NestFate <- c(rep(" ",4),"Fledged"," ","Depredated")
data <- data.frame(NestID,JulianDate,Stage,HostEggs,HostYoung,NSTLAge,NestFate)

InitiationDate <- c()
nests <- names(table(NestID)) #I got the names of the nests
for(i in 1:length(nests)){
  p <- min(which(data$NestID==nests[i])) #This is to see the position where the i nest beggings
  if(data$Stage[p]=="IB"){
    a <- max(which(data$Stage[which(data$NestID==nests[i])]=="IB"))
    b <- min(which(data$Stage[which(data$NestID==nests[i])]=="NG"))
    InitiationDate[i] <- mean(data$JulianDate[c(a,b)]) - 12
  } else if(data$Stage[p]=="NG"){
    InitiationDate[i] <- data$JulianDate[p] - data$NSTLAge[p] - 12
  }
}
names(InitiationDate) <- nests; InitiationDate
```